# Warum benutzt dieser Schriftsteller "deren" statt "ihre"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Folgendes erscheint im Buch "Der Vorleser" von Schlink:

> Er [Hannas Verteidiger] setzte sich.  Er war der einzige junge
> Verteidiger, die anderen waren alt, einige, wie sich bald zeigte, alte
> Nazis.  Hannas Verteidiger vermied **deren** Jargon und Thesen.

Ich verstehe, da ich ein paar Beiträge gelesen habe, die dieses Thema betreffen, dass "deren" und "dessen" manchmal "ihr", "sein" usw. ersetzen können, besonders wenn es den Satz klarer macht.  Aber warum wird "deren" in diesem Absatz gebraucht? Liegt es daran, dass "ihre" doppeldeutig wäre, weil es sich auf entweder Hanna oder die anderen Verteidiger beziehen könnte?  Wenn ja, warum ist "deren" überhaupt klarer?

Danke!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich denke nicht, dass es hier so sehr um Klarheit der Zuordnung geht. Sehen wir uns zunächst einmal einen Satz an, in dem das von Bedeutung wäre.

> Lena und Paul trafen auf eine Gruppe von Touristen. Lena gefielen deren Sandalen nicht.

Hier wäre es zweideutig, *ihre Sandalen* zu verwenden, weil nicht klar wäre, ob von Lenas oder von den Sandalen der Toursiten die Rede ist.

In Schlinks Sätzen dagegen geht es eindeutig um den Vergleich (insbesondere den Unterschied) zwischen Hannahs und den anderen Verteidigern. Davon abgesehen, dass *deren* (wie @Arno in seiner inzwischen gelöschten Antwort m.E. ganz richtig schrieb) eine größere Distanz zum Ausdruck bringt, spielt hier auch die Grammatik eine Rolle.

Bei der Verwendung von *ihre* statt *deren* müsste der Satz korrekterweise lauten:

> Hannahs Verteidiger vermied ihren Jargon und ihre Thesen.

Die Doppelung ließe sich vermeiden, wenn man *Jargon und Thesen* als Einheit betrachtet. Dann hieße es wegen der Mehrzahl (mit unterschiedlichen Genera) aber richtig:

> Hannahs Verteidiger vermied ihre [Jargon und Thesen].

Sehr viel eleganter erscheint es mir da, mit

> Hannahs Verteidiger vermied **deren** Jargon und Thesen.

zwei Fliegen mit einer Klappe zu schlagen.

Comment: Danke!  Mir scheint jetzt, dass es mindestens drei Gründe gibt, den Genitiv so zu verwenden - (1) die Klärung der erwähnten Person oder Personen, (2) um Distanz zu schaffen und (3) im Fall einer solchen Einheit um Eleganz zu schaffen. Aber ich bin mir im Moment noch nicht sicher, ob ich sogar den ersten Grund völlig verstehen.  Warum darf im Sandalen-Beispiel "deren" gar nicht "Lenas" bedeuten? Würde es einfach so komisch klingen, sich auf Lena so zu beziehen, dass "deren" sich auf die Touristen beziehen muss? Oder gibt es einen grammatischeren Grund?

Comment: Vielleicht als Faustregel (die wie alle Faustregeln mit Vorsicht zu genießen ist): wenn *deren* benutzt wird wo auch *ihren* möglich wäre, deutet das darauf hin, dass von dem naheliegenden Bezug zwischen Subjekt und Objekt abgewichen werden soll. Ansonsten wird *ihren* benutzt.